# Unable to import from a relative path using node js

Tags: node.js, cucumber, webdriver-io

Currently my automation framework built on Cucumber+ Nodejs+ webdriverio. It has the following structure for data files

```
    main/
    ..../data
    ......../region1.js
    ......../region2.js
```

In my step definition  I need to import the data files so that my functions can use the data as per the region I intend to execute which I provide during run time

How should I mention my import command? for example, I tried the following but that does not work
import users from '../main/data/*';

Comment: Are you trying to import `region1` or `region2` into a module outside of main?

Comment: @JeremyHamm no .. its in the same module as "/data" but the factor is the data I need depends on the region i execute which I convey during run time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Posting a solution which I came across

Step 1: Add an index.js file under /data folder
Step 2: Adding the following code in index.js

```
    import * as region1 from "../region1"
    import * as region2 from "../region2"

    export {
     region1,
     region2
    }
```

Now in the file that requires this data, add the following import line

```
    import myValues from "./main/data"
```

You need to pass your required region from command line as an environment variable lets say as REGION

If you want to access a value from respective region file based on value passed in REGION, the following code will work

const myreqData = myValues[process.env.REGION].<respective node in the js]